# .then is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this error, when trying to get response from my service, in which i have placed my Ajax call! I want the controller code to delay that is why i am returning a promise from service. But I am getting `.then of undefined` error.
Here is the code

```
app.service('abc', function(){

    var function() {

        return $http({method : "POST",
                            url :"url",
                            data:{
                                a}
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {        
                 return response;
        })
    }
});
```

in controller

```
var promise=servicename.functionname();

promise.then(res)
{}
```

.then of `undefined` is the error I am getting. Any solution?

Comment: Please mention your code piece clearly.

Comment: inject `$http` into your service: `app.service('abc', function($http){`

Comment: `var function()`  ?  That's not valid JavaScript.  And your braces arn't in correct opening and closing pairs.  This is just nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update service and inject $http

```
app.service('abc', function ($http) {
    this.functionName = function (data) {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: data
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            return response.data;
        })
    };
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller('myController', function (abc) {
    abc.functionName({
        a: 'a'
    }).then((data) => console.log(data))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the code will not wait the return inside then() and it will execute the code ahead. And as it does no find any return  statement it will return undefined.
To fix this in the service function you will return just the promise
so your return statement will look something like this

```
return $http({
           method : "POST",
           url :"url",
           data:{a}
   })
```

The controller code will be same